# Full listing of Facebook City-IDs and names for a country

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, geolocation

I'm looking for a way to get a full listing of the city IDs that Facebook Graph API uses identify cities in a particular country (e.g. US), ideally together with their names, states and other details. The closest I found was this API, which requires a substring of the city name to be supplied in the query - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/audiences/reference/targeting-search/
Is a dataset like this available some place? Or else how could I obtain it from the Facebook API?

Comment: The way I intend to address this is by getting a listing of all the cities in the US 5-digit ZIP code, and then get their Facebook city IDs. I don't know if this will be complete, but it should be sufficient for practical purposes.